# Cygwin and Python "ImportError: No module named request "

Tags: python, curl, cygwin, importerror

Trying to import urllib.request and run python in cygwin but consistently getting the error "ImportError: No module named request "

I looked at another stackoverflow page and followed instructions to reinstall cygwin and  enable curl. Still no results.

I don't know if this is a python problem, a cygwin problem, or an operator error

I'm running Python 3 on Windows 32 through cygwin

Comment: Sounds like you are running Python 2 instead. What does `import sys; print(sys.version)` show?

Comment: Ah you're right. I'm actually running python 2.7. I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: How do you change the cygwin path from python 2.7 to python 3?

Comment: This could be an issue with the `$PYTHONPATH` environmental variable.